# how to access Salesforce Attachment Body (base64 binary data) using java?

Tags: java, web-services, salesforce, webservices-client, salesforce-service-cloud

I am working on java application for getting attachments from salesforce.

I have to show the salesforce attachments in my java application for particular object like Leads,Contacts etc. For that i am using Rest Api and got response body. But in response body there is url but i want binary data of attachment body.

I get response in body in following format:

```
{
Body = "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004SRFlEAO/Body";
ContentType = "application/video";
Name = "Video.MOV";
attributes =     {
   type = Attachment;
    url = "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004SRFlEAO";
};
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You get the actual attachment by performing a GET request to the Url returned in the Body field.